# checking success of taking input

Tags: c++, c, input

I'm new to `C++`. I had some knowledge of `C`  ,and I know shouldn't assume `C` rules are same as `C++`. I'm just looking for some same solution.

for example In C when we use:

```
int a;
if (scanf ("%d", &a) != 1);
```

to check if an valid value entered .For example if instead of a integer ,a char was taken as input this will tell us `scanf` failed to take an integer as input.

but in `C++` I debugged this code when I gave input `m` to program:

```
    int a;
    cin >> a;
```

and it assigned `0` to `a` ,but I did same thing with `scanf` and value of `a` was `-858993460`.(while default value of `a` in both langues was `-858993460`)

so here is my problem , How can I know if `cin` failed to take valid input? and is it usual that , `0` is assigned to `a` in `C++` code? and if it's usual how can I know entered data was really `0` or was a failure result? is there a way for checking success of `cin`?

PS: sorry if the question is stupid. I'm competently new to `c++`.

Comment: "I know shouldn't compare C rules with C++" why not? You just should not assume that they are the same

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408117/using-cin-to-error-handle). `cin` returns a value that indicates whether the input operation succeeded or failed.

Comment: Neither of the 'a's are initialised to anything, they simply have the random value that was at that location in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this by good() function like

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     int i=0;

     if( ! ( (cin>>i).good() ) )
        cout<<"Error";
     else
        cout<<i;

     return 0;
}
```

See below:

`cin` returns reference to it and istream (cin is a object of istream) contains a function good() return true if the stream is in good state otherwise return false.

Comment: `if( ! ( (cin>>i).good() ) )` is the same as `if (!cin >> i)`

Comment: This would print "Error" in case a value was successfully extracted but the stream was then at end-of-file, for example. The way to check if the extraction was successful is to check `fail()` eg replace `! ( (cin>>i).good() )` with `(cin>>i).fail()`.